# How to program the P5Z22V10-da?

Tags: fpga, programmable-logic

I got a handful of [these](http://www.datasheets360.com/pdf/7940389213400287282) chips at my job when they were being thrown away. They are Programmable Logic Devices. I found a datasheet online from 1997 that says that xilinx bought the ip for a similar chip, but the website is [dataman.com](http://www.dataman.com/media/datasheet/Philips/P5Z22V10.pdf) and I don't know if it is a reliable source, and the information is 20 years old.

I've done a little bit of hobby fpga programming with verilog and I wonder how similar this procedure is, if it is similar at all.

I've found [atmel](http://www.atmel.com/Images/DOC0485.PDF), [academic](http://eelinux.ee.usm.maine.edu/courses/ele373/pldbasics2.pdf), [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmable_logic_device), [hackaday](http://hackaday.com/2008/12/11/how-to-programmable-logic-devices-cpld/), and [instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Programmable-Logic-Devices/)tutorials but they are all about either chips that come on a board with some sort of serial port or else they are circuit diagrams and I think they expect someone with a different education than mine to take the next step.

update:
found [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2u77sAfka4w) [two](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQwsclx3UbA) [three](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X28s0zHMVwM) videos on youtube and skimming them shows some talk about the circuit diagrams. Ill come back if I find an answer and maybe answer this question myself.

Comment: I admire your inquisitive mind Julian but they were a struggle to design more than basic circuits for. I can't help you on getting them programmed but I can encourage you to jump forward into CPLDs and FPGAs and put your good learning into something you can use again and again. Good luck with wherever it takes you :-)

Comment: The 22V10 is a PLD ...just like a CPLD in most respects, it's just not very dense (fewer cells). These are mainly obsolete now, but if you picked up a lifetime supply you can use something like Xilinx ISE to program them, or still available from multiple sources is WinCUPL (http://www.atmel.com/tools/WINCUPL.aspx ... http://ee-classes.usc.edu/ee459/library/documents/CUPL_Reference.pdf). There are plenty of CPLD/FPGA programmers that still support them

Comment: A micro-power 22V10, awesome!

Comment: @Jack good tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC DataMan were a manufacturer of quite respectable EPROM/PLD/PAL/GAL/CPLD programming hardware back then, In fact there may still be an old Dataman S3 kicking around the office.

I would however strongly second Tonys suggestion to learn on something more modern, it will be far more useful.

Comment: sounds like good advice. Learning these old technologies can take as much time as learning a new technology but it doesn't have the same payoff I guess